# Complex query in ZEND

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to execute the following query in ZEND 1.12.

```
SELECT B . * , COUNT( * ) AS CT
FROM `blogpost` B
JOIN `blog_likes` L
WHERE B.`blog_id` = L.`blog_id`
AND L.liked_post = 'Y'
GROUP BY B.`blog_id`
ORDER BY CT DESC
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

I tried the following code, but that is not returning the correct output as I want :

```
$this->getDbTable()->select()
->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->from(array('B' => 'blogpost'), array( "B.*", "COUNT(*) AS CT"))
->join(array('L' => 'blog_likes'), 'B.blog_id = L.blog_id')                 
->where("L.liked_post =?", 'Y')
->group ("B.blog_id")
->order ("CT DESC")
->limit($limit);
```

Can any one please help me?

Comment: What's wrong with the output of your code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to pass to the from and to every join you write, the columns that you want to select from that table, thus, if you don't want to select any column from the L table, your join should look like:

```
->join(array('L' => 'blog_likes'), 'B.blog_id = L.blog_id', array())
```

If you leave the last parameter empty, it'll select all the columns (L.*).

Second, to the array of columns that you pass to a from or join, you can set aliases by using the value of that key, i.e.:

```
 ->from(array('B' => 'blogpost'), array( "B.*", "CT" => "COUNT(*)"))
```

This makes it more readable.

And last, but not least, you are COUNTING on the from, that won't count all the rows that the inner table has, but only the from's. So, if you want to count the rows from the final table, as I guess you are trying to with the SQL sentence, what you have to do is:

```
$this->getDbTable()->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array('B' => 'blogpost'), array( "B.*"))
    ->join(array('L' => 'blog_likes'), 'B.blog_id = L.blog_id', array("CT" => "COUNT(*)"))                 
    ->where("L.liked_post =?", 'Y')
    ->group ("B.blog_id")
    ->order ("CT DESC")
    ->limit($limit);
```

The count can be a little bit strange to use, so I would suggest you to use this way instead:

```
$this->getDbTable()->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array('B' => 'blogpost'), array())
    ->join(array('L' => 'blog_likes'), 'B.blog_id = L.blog_id', array())                 
    ->where("L.liked_post =?", 'Y')
    ->group ("B.blog_id")
    ->order ("CT DESC")
    ->limit($limit)
    ->columns(array(
         "B.*",
         "CT" => "COUNT(*)"    
     ));
```

To read more, please, go to the [Zend_Db_Select documentation.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html)

I hope this helps.